# What is the term for arbitrary disqualification?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for the term that applies when someone disqualifies another party from social groups membership.

ex: "You're not a real fan if..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A term that comes to mind is [**petty**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/petty) or - taken in another direction - [**discriminatory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discriminatory), but perhaps you are looking for the "[**No True Scotsman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)" or "Appeal to Purity" fallacy

> No true Scotsman, or appeal to purity, is an informal fallacy in which *one attempts to protect a universal generalization from counterexamples by changing the definition in an ad hoc fashion to exclude the counterexample*
>
> Person A: "No Scotsman puts sugar on his porridge."
>
> Person B: "But my uncle Angus is a Scotsman and he puts sugar on his porridge."
>
> Person A: "But no true Scotsman puts sugar on his porridge."